# Is it possible to send and receive the whole system traffic through firefox?

Tags: networking, 16.04, firefox, proxy

I have a proxy add-on installed on my firefox and I want to use that proxy as a system-wide proxy.

I wonder if it is possible to send and receive system network traffic through firefox. I have already tried to set system proxy the same as what shows in firefox proxy configuration when the add-on is active, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Firefox is a browser, so it handles only stuff like HTTP and HTTPs traffic. I don't think it can handle other types of protocols, like DNS requests for instance. This is something that is done on completely different level of network stack

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks for your explanation but are you sure about this? To set a system-wide proxy you just need to enter proxy for HTTP and HTTPS and FTP and Socks protocols, which my proxy add-on supports all of them. (They are set in firefox when the add-on is active)

Comment: Pretty sure (although I'm no networking expert), because  "whole traffic" involves lots of different protocols. System proxy for http will handle only http requests, but then what about VoIP ? what about DNS ? what about other services that use UDP protocol ?

Comment: Ok I surrender :) It can't be done. I didn't know much about other protocols, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Firefox can only handle traffic like HTTP/HTTPS, FTP, etc and the addon would only be able to use the proxy for traffic happening inside of Firefox.